# Can't pull image from docker registry when docker is pointing to a swarm

Tags: docker, docker-machine, dockerhub, docker-swarm

I'm having an issue with `google container registry` and `dockerhub` where `docker pull` returns the following errors.

gcr

> Error: Status 403 trying to pull repository PROJECT_ID/IMAGE_NAME: "Unable to access the repository: PROJECT_ID/IMAGE_NAME; please verify that it exists and you have permission to access it (no valid credential was supplied)."

dockerhub

> Using default tag: latest test-node0: Pulling
>   k8tems/hello-world:latest... : Error: image k8tems/hello-world not
>   found  Error: image k8tems/hello-world not found

This only happens when docker is pointing to a swarm.

Steps to reproduce:

```
DOCKER_REGISTRY=asia.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID
KEY_STORE=test-keystore
NODE_BASE=test-node

echo pushing hello-world image to gcr
docker pull hello-world
docker tag hello-world $DOCKER_REGISTRY/hello-world
docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY/hello-world

echo setting up key store
docker-machine create \
    -d digitalocean \
    "$KEY_STORE"

docker $(docker-machine config "$KEY_STORE") run -d \
    -p "8500:8500" \
    -h "consul" \
    progrium/consul -server -bootstrap

eval $(docker-machine env "$KEY_STORE")

docker-machine create \
        -d digitalocean \
        --swarm \
        --swarm-master \
        --swarm-discovery="consul://$(docker-machine ip "$KEY_STORE"):8500" \
        --engine-opt="cluster-store=consul://$(docker-machine ip "$KEY_STORE"):8500" \
        --engine-opt="cluster-advertise=eth0:2376" \
        "$NODE_BASE"0

echo this fails
eval $(docker-machine env -swarm "$NODE_BASE"0)
docker pull $DOCKER_REGISTRY/hello-world

echo this succeeds
eval $(docker-machine env "$NODE_BASE"0)
docker pull $DOCKER_REGISTRY/hello-world
```

Along with the above snippet, I've also tried forcing the remote docker version to `1.10.3` and swarm to `1.1.3` but the error still persists.

```
ubuntu:~$ docker-machine ls | grep test
test-keystore                -        digitalocean   Running   tcp://:2376                                       v1.10.3   
test-node0                   *        digitalocean   Running   tcp://:2376    test-node0 (master)                v1.10.3   
ubuntu:~$ docker exec swarm-agent-master /swarm -v
swarm version 1.1.3 (7e9c6bd)
ubuntu:~$ docker -v
Docker version 1.10.2, build c3959b1
```

Is there anything I can do to make this work with the `-swarm` flag or do I have to run the pull command for each node?

Answer (score 0):

Try JSON key file! It is a long-lived credential and much more consistent than access token when you are using clusters like swarm or kubernetes.

Example command:
docker login -e 1234@5678.com -u _json_key -p "$(cat keyfile.json)" https://gcr.io

Here is the page with more details:
https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#using_a_json_key_file

Comment: I created a Compute engine default service account and logged in with `docker login -e 1234@5678.com -u _json_key -p "$(cat ~/gcr-key.json)" https://asia.gcr.io` but I still get 403 with `-swarm`